# Dataproc: update log level in Spark shell

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter, google-cloud-dataproc, spark-shell

I use Jupyter terminal for accessing the driver of Dataproc cluster. This is my gateway to the cluster, and I do not have direct SSH enabled for the driver machine.
When I launch spark-shell , I keep getting these info, debug, Contextcleaner messages throughout my session and kind of disturbs my coding efforts. Is there a way to turn these off ?

```
scala> 22/10/11 15:47:31 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (10.22.86.219:43504) with ID 2
22/10/11 15:47:31 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (10.22.86.217:54770) with ID 1
22/10/11 15:47:31 INFO org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager cluster:39607 with 5.6 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(2, cluster, 39607, None)
22/10/11 15:47:31 INFO org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager cluster.internal:36731 with 5.6 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(1, cluster, 36731, None)
22/10/11 15:47:31 WARN com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopSyncableOutputStream: hflush(): No-op due to rate limit (RateLimiter[stableRate=0.2qps]): readers will *not* yet see flushed data for gs://bucket/application_1665502930299_0001.lz4.inprogress
22/10/11 15:47:31 WARN com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopSyncableOutputStream: hflush(): No-op due to rate limit (RateLimiter[stableRate=0.2qps]): readers will *not* yet see flushed data for gs://bucket/application_1665502930299_0001.lz4.inprogress
22/10/11 15:47:31 WARN com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopSyncableOutputStream: hflush(): No-op due to rate limit (RateLimiter[stableRate=0.2qps]): readers will *not* yet see flushed data for gs://bucket/application_1665502930299_0001.lz4.inprogress
22/10/11 15:54:51 INFO org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 56
22/10/11 15:54:51 INFO org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 31
22/10/11 15:54:51 INFO org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 63
22/10/11 15:54:51 INFO org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 30
22/10/11 15:54:51 INFO org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 44
22/10/11 15:54:51 INFO org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 32
22/10/11 15:54:51 INFO org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 35
22/10/11 15:54:53 INFO org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5 stored as values in memory (estimated size 23.1 KB, free 3.8 GB)
22/10/11 15:54:53 INFO org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 7.6 KB, free 3.8 GB)
22/10/11 15:54:53 INFO org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_5_piece0 in memory on clusterurl:33625 (size: 7.6 KB, free: 3.8 GB)
22/10/11 15:54:53 INFO org.apache.spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 5 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1184
22/10/11 15:54:53 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 4 (MapPartitionsRDD[9] at show at <console>:39) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(1))
22/10/11 15:54:53 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnScheduler: Adding task set 4.0 with 1 tasks
22/10/11 15:54:53 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.FairSchedulableBuilder: Added task set TaskSet_4.0 tasks to pool default
22/10/11 15:54:53 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 7, cluster.internal, executor 1, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7908 bytes)
22/10/11 15:54:53 INFO org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_5_piece0 in memory on cluster.internal:36731 (size: 7.6 KB, free: 5.6 GB)
22/10/11 15:54:54 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 7) in 558 ms on cluster.internal (executor 1) (1/1)
22/10/11 15:54:54 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 4.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool default
22/10/11 15:54:54 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 4 (show at <console>:39) finished in 0.571 s
22/10/11 15:54:54 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 4 finished: show at <console>:39, took 0.575517 s
```

Comment: UPDATE :

After trying several things, I was able to contain the messages. Below thing worked for me.


```scala> import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}

scala> val rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()

scala> Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark").setLevel(Level.WARN)```

Comment: Just curious does your cluster set `log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=INFO` explicitly? because by default it is WARN.

Comment: It's set by admins who provide managed service to Dataproc.

Answer (score 1):

The logs are controlled by `/etc/spark/conf/log4j.properties`, the default root log level is INFO, but in spark-shell, the root level is overridden as WARN. I guess the reason you see logs like `INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler` is because your cluster has settings like `log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=INFO` in the file.

There are several way you can change log settings for spark-shell:

#### Session level

1. Run `sc.setLogLevel("WARN")` in spark-shell which will update the root log level for the whole process. It has the same effect as

```
scala> import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
scala> Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.WARN)
```

2. Get the specific logger and set level, e.g.:

```
scala> import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
scala> Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark").setLevel(Level.WARN)
```

3. Make a copy of `/etc/spark/conf/log4j.properties` to `/tmp/spark-log4j.properties`, edit it with the desired log settings, then run `spark-shell --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///tmp/spark-log4j.properties`.

#### Cluster level

1. Edit `/etc/spark/conf/log4j.properties` and set higher log levels for the spammy packages, then run `spark-shell`.
2. When creating the cluster, add `--properties ^#^spark-log4j:log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=WARN#...`, which will update the config file under the hood.

Comment: I tried 1st option since I did not want to change it cluster level. It did not work and still the messages were coming. However, I  used below steps which solved the issue.

```scala> import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}

scala> val rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()

scala> Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark").setLevel(Level.WARN)```

Comment: Thanks! I improved my answer based on your findings.